# Can I float an element next to the previous element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Consider the following bog-standard paragraphs-with-sidebar layout. The layout has two issues: first, the sidebar (which will be navigation stuff in my case) will be seen first by the browser, resulting in some accessibility issues with screen readers and text-only browsers. So the element should be after the article. But in that case I can't rely on the tried & true `float:right` mechanism; all absolute positioning will lead to problems. The second issue relates to the first one; with narrow viewports I don't want it to float next to the text and want it placed after.

How can I achieve the same look but with the two elements `#main` and `#sidebar` swapped places?

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #abc;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="main">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can use FlexBox, you can use the ordering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use the FlexBox, you can use `order` to swap it left and right.

I have done it for you:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#main {
  width: 85%;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #abc;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
      here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
      Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: In your example the sidebar still comes before `#main` in the actual HTML

Comment: @progo Sorry, you want the sidebar later? You can do it. Lemme quickly update.

Comment: @progo Updated... The order of your code is not a big deal, but `order` is the main thing there. Check out the updated answer. `:D`

Comment: I'll study the browser compatibility for a bit but I think this is it

Comment: I highly recommend Praveen's flexbox answer. In today's browsers, you should have no problem with flexbox compatibility. However, if you happen to still need to support very old browsers, I can post you an old fashioned grid layout answer in a bit

Comment: @OzzyTheGiant: sure, go ahead. Always interested to see different solutions to real-world problems.

Answer (score 1):

The way I used to do float layout was to float left the first item, and then float right the second item in a row. This means you can have your #main element come first in the markup. After that, you should give your #main element an arbitrary percent width. Keep in mind that because the #sidebar has fixed width, you will have to use a media query to fix its layout once the #sidebar no longer fits and gets bumped to the next row. It's up to you how you want to lay it out there, but for argument purposes, you could try to simply remove the floats at that point. I assume there are no other elements above or below these two that you would have to worry about. For the media query, I used 408px for max-width but this may be different on your web page.

```css
#main {
  width: 60%;
  float:left;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #abc;
  float:right;
}

#main p {margin-top:0;}

@media screen and (max-width:408px) {
  #main {
    float:none;
  }
  
  #sidebar {
    float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
</div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: You can safely ignore the margin-top:0 style, that's just me being picky about <p> margins

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to fake a float element with pseudo-element before, and use position absolute to place the sidebar on top of it.

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
}
#main:before {
 content:'';
 float:right;
 background:red;
 width:150px;
 height:200px;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #abc;
  position:absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
</div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: Op specifically asked for non-absolute solutions, though.

Comment: its a suggestion, I don't see another way, flexbox will not simulate the paragraph behavior of surrounding an image

Comment: This is actually amazing, if a bit hackish. This won't be suitable for my needs as the dimensions of the sidebar live on the content. Very well working solution anyway!